# Match "_<digit>string" wth a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings like

- xxx_2pathway
- xxx_6pathway
- xxx_pathway

So I have a string followed by an underscore and "pathway". There may be a digit between the underscore and "pathway". How can I match and replace everything except xxx with a regular expression in Java?

This does not work:

```
pathnameRaw = pathnameRaw.replace("_\\dpathway","");
```

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "does not work".  In most regex libraries, your example should match the first and second cases, but not the latter because you the digit is not optional.  If it didn't match *at all*, that implies that `\\d` isn't matching against e.g. `2` for you, which is an important distinction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is almost fine. Since the digit is optional, add a `?` at the end of `\\d`.

Also the [replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method does not use regex. Use [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/yNiYw)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know that I have to use replaceAll to use regex in Java, but now it works.

Comment: You should accept codaddict's answer as the correct one then.

Comment: Done. I had to wait 5 minutes before I was able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`"_[0-9]?pathway"`